# Get difference of two times android

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I am trying to get the difference between two user set times. I am very close to getting this to work but I cant get the difference from one day to another. for example if the start time was 11:00 pm and the end time was 1:00 AM it will say 21:00 hours because it does not know what to do once the day changes. please help, heres my time-picker code.

```
    // Creates Simple Date Format//
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    // Parses StartTime 24 Hour Format//
    try {
        if (military_start_time == null) {
        } else {

            date1 = sdf.parse(military_start_time);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Parses EndTime 24 Hour Format//
    try {
        if (military_end_time == null) {

        } else {
            date2 = sdf.parse(military_end_time);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // If End Time Equals Null Do Nothing//
    if (military_end_time  != null) {

        // If Start Time Equals Null Do Nothing//
        if (military_start_time != null) {

            // Subtracts Two Times In 24 Hour Format And Then Puts It Into 12 Hour Format//
            long differance = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
            int days = (int) (differance / (1000*60*60*24));
            int hours = (int) ((differance - (1000*60*60*24*days)) / (1000*60*60));
            int min = (int) (differance - (1000*60*60*24*days) - (1000*60*60*hours)) / (1000*60);
            String diffTime = (hours<0 ? "0" + -hours : hours) + ":" + (min < 10 ? "0" + min : min);

            // Set Time Differance//
            totaltime.setText(diffTime);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Joda-Time library. See [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diff);
long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);
long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff);
long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have my own custome method which i am using from long time,You can use it. It will sure works for you.Below is code -

```
public static String getTimeDifferance(String startTime,String endTime){
    try{
        Date time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(endTime);
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.setTime(time1);

        Date time2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(startTime);
        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.setTime(time2);

        Date x = calendar1.getTime();
        Date xy = calendar2.getTime();
        long diff = x.getTime() - xy.getTime();
        int diffMinutes = (int) (diff / (60 * 1000));

        int diffHours = diffMinutes / 60;
        System.out.println("diff hours" + diffHours);
        if(diffMinutes>59){
            diffMinutes = diffMinutes%60;
        }
        String totalDiff = diffHours+":"+diffMinutes+":00";
        return totalDiff;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Hope i am helpfull to you. All the best!!

**EDITED**

Update your code as -

```
if (military_start_time != null) {
    String timeDiff = getTimeDifferance(military_start_time,military_end_time);
    totaltime.setText(timeDiff);
}
```

Comment: can you help me with adding this into my code at the top. I'm having trouble implementing it. Thanks

Comment: Update: I added the new code but it comes out weird. For instance if I make startime 2:00 and endtime 4:00 the total time displays as -2: -120

Comment: its working code,i am using same code.Please try changeing getTimeDifferance(military_start_time,military_end_time);